# Powershell Start-Process for Teams

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I use the following script to clear the cache of—and start—Teams.

It worked as expected for some time. Now I get some strange behaviours like:

1. When I close powershell, Teams closes too
2. Before I close PS there appear some errors

```
# start Teams
# Start-Process -File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Teams\current\Teams.exe" -ArgumentList '--processStart "Teams.exe"'
# Write-Host "Teams Process Sucessfully Started" 
# Start-Sleep -Seconds 5


#Stop Teams process 
Get-Process -ProcessName Teams -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Stop-Process -Force 
Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
Write-Host "Teams Process Sucessfully Stopped" 

#Clear Team Cache
try{
#  Get-ChildItem -Path $env:APPDATA\"Microsoft\Teams" | Remove-Item -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue # Clear.all
Get-ChildItem -Path $env:APPDATA\"Microsoft\Teams\blob_storage" | Remove-Item -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Get-ChildItem -Path $env:APPDATA\"Microsoft\Teams\databases" | Remove-Item -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Get-ChildItem -Path $env:APPDATA\"Microsoft\Teams\cache" | Remove-Item -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Get-ChildItem -Path $env:APPDATA\"Microsoft\Teams\gpucache" | Remove-Item -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Get-ChildItem -Path $env:APPDATA\"Microsoft\Teams\Indexeddb" | Remove-Item -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Get-ChildItem -Path $env:APPDATA\"Microsoft\Teams\Local Storage" | Remove-Item -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Get-ChildItem -Path $env:APPDATA\"Microsoft\Teams\tmp" | Remove-Item -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Write-Host "Teams Cache Cleaned" 
}catch{
echo $_ 
}

#Remove Credential from Credential manager
$credential = cmdkey /list | ForEach-Object{if($_ -like "*Target:*" -and $_ -like "*msTeams*"){cmdkey /del:($_ -replace " ","" -replace "Target:","")}}

#Remove Reg.Key
$Regkeypath= "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\Teams" 
$value = (Get-ItemProperty $Regkeypath).HomeUserUpn -eq $null
If ($value -eq $False) 
{ 
  Remove-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\Teams" -Name "HomeUserUpn"
  Write-Host "The registry value Sucessfully removed" 
} 
Else { Write-Host "The registry value does not exist"}

#Get Desktop-config.json
$TeamsFolders = "$env:APPDATA\Microsoft\Teams"
try{
    $SourceDesktopConfigFile = "$TeamsFolders\desktop-config.json"
    $desktopConfig = (Get-Content -Path $SourceDesktopConfigFile | ConvertFrom-Json)
}
catch{ Write-Host "Failed to open Desktop-config.json" }

#Overwrite the desktop-config.json
Write-Host "Modify desktop-Config.Json"
try{
    $desktopConfig.isLoggedOut = $true
    $desktopConfig.upnWindowUserUpn =""; #The email used to sign in | also: whoami /upn
    $desktopConfig.userUpn ="";
    $desktopConfig.userOid ="";
    $desktopConfig.userTid = "";
    $desktopConfig.homeTenantId ="";
    $desktopConfig.webAccountId="";
    $desktopConfig | ConvertTo-Json -Compress | Set-Content -Path $SourceDesktopConfigFile -Force
}
catch{ Write-Host "Failed to overwrite desktop-config.json" }
Write-Host "Modify desktop-Config.Json - Finished"

#Delete the Cookies file. This is a fix for when the joining as anonymous, and prevents the last used guest name from being reused.
Get-ChildItem "$TeamsFolders\Cookies" | Remove-Item

#Lastly delete the storage.json, this corrects some error that MSTeams otherwise would have when logging in again.
Get-ChildItem "$TeamsFolders\storage.json" | Remove-Item


#Try to remove the Link School/Work account if there was one. It can be created if the first time you sign in, the user all
# $LocalPackagesFolder ="$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Packages"
# $AADBrokerFolder = Get-ChildItem -Path $LocalPackagesFolder -Recurse -Include "Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin_*";
# $AADBrokerFolder = $AADBrokerFolder[0];
# Get-ChildItem "$AADBrokerFolder\AC\TokenBroker\Accounts" | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
# Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

# start Teams
Start-Process -File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Teams\current\Teams.exe" -ArgumentList '--processStart "Teams.exe"'
# "$($env:USERProfile)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\Update.exe" 
Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
Write-Host "Teams Process Sucessfully Started" 

# Stop for testpurposes
pause
```

---

**SIDENOTE**

Teams is installed as per Microsoft recommendation for VDI setups.
(Citrix VDI/VDA, HDX Optimized)

---

It worked as expected for some time. Now I get some strange behaviours like:

- When I close powershell, Teams closes too
- Before I close PS there appear some errors

  - [Screenshot of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbv1V.png)

Comment: _"Before I close PS there appear some errors"_. Please shoiw those errors in Full (not in a comment, but in your post by clicking [edit])

Comment: Thanks. I hope a screenshot is fine too.

Comment: Teams sucks doesn't it?  I just know not to join the computer to the work account.